# Variadic nested loops

Tags: c++, algorithm

I am working on a N dimensional grid.
I would like to generate nested loops depending on any dimension (2D, 3D, 4D, etc...).
How can I do that in an elegant and fast way ?  Below a simple illustration of my problem.
I am writing in C++ but I think this kind of question can be useful for other languages.
I need to know the indices (i,j,k...) in my do stuff part.
Edit : lower_bound and upper_bound represents the indexes in the grid so they are always positive.

```
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    // Dimension here is 3D
    std::vector<size_t> lower_bound({4,2,1});
    std::vector<size_t> upper_bound({16,47,9});

    for (size_t i = lower_bound[0]; i < upper_bound[0]; i ++)
        for (size_t j = lower_bound[1]; j < upper_bound[1]; j ++)
            for (size_t k = lower_bound[2]; k < upper_bound[2]; k ++)
                // for (size_t l = lower_bound[3]; l < upper_bound[3]; l ++)
                //  ...
                {
                    // Do stuff such as
                    grid({i,j,k}) = 2 * i + 3 *j - 4 * k;
                    // where grid size is the total number of vertices
                }
}
```

Comment: ...and you are really sure about the `// Do stuff` part??

Comment: What do you mean ? I am calling my index grid like grid[{i,j,k}] which is generic for any dimension. Maybe I can do differently but I am still interested by the answer

Comment: the grit may be variadic, but not your "literal" source code `{i,j,k}`

Comment: @Eugen Sh  I also thought about recursion thanks. Might be a little complicated if I want to keep the indices. Could you provide an elegant solution ?

Comment: @Wolf  I would call *grid[coord]* where coord is a N dimensional indexes vector for genericity purpose I can provide this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following may help:

```
bool increment(
    std::vector<int>& v,
    const std::vector<int>& lower,
    const std::vector<int>& upper)
{
    assert(v.size() == lower.size());
    assert(v.size() == upper.size());

    for (auto i = v.size(); i-- != 0; ) {
        ++v[i];
        if (v[i] != upper[i]) {
            return true;
        }
        v[i] = lower[i];
    }
    return false;
}
```

And use it that way:

```
int main() {
    const std::vector<int> lower_bound({4,2,1});
    const std::vector<int> upper_bound({6,7,4});
    std::vector<int> current = lower_bound;

    do {
        std::copy(current.begin(), current.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
        std::cout << std::endl;
    } while (increment(current, lower_bound, upper_bound));
}
```

[Live demo](https://ideone.com/d7dCn1)

Comment: This works really fine for my purpose thank you again ! Just to mention a sanitizer message using Clang compiler : *runtime error: unsigned integer overflow: 0 - 1 cannot be represented in type 'unsigned long'* . The line concerned is *for (auto i = current.size(); i -- != 0; )*.

Comment: @coincoin: You may move the decrement inside the loop body to remove that message.

Answer (score 1):

A recursive function may help you achieve what you want.

```
void Recursive( int comp )
{
    if(comp == dimension)
    {
         // Do stuff
    }
    else
    {
         for (int e = lower_bound[comp]; e < upper_bound[comp]; e++)
             Recursive(comp+1);
    }
}
```

Some additions may be necessary in the function signature if you need to know the current indices (i,j,k,...) in your "Do Stuff" section.

This is a clean way to have access to these indices

```
void Recursive( int comp, int dimension )
{
    static std::vector<int> indices;
    if( comp == 0 ) // initialize indices
    {
        indices.clear();
        indices.resize(dimension, 0);
    }

    if(comp == dimension -1)
    {
         // Do stuff
    }
    else
    {
         int& e = indices[comp];
         for (e = lower_bound[comp]; e < upper_bound[comp]; e++)
             Recursive(comp+1);
    }
}
```

This is however not usable along multiple threads, due to the shared static vector.

Comment: Thanks I like the idea but I indeed need to get these current indices. Trying to find a nice way to do it.

Comment: You could use either a [Variadic Argument](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variadic_arguments) or pass a vector to store those indices. Or you could also keep them in some accessible space, like as a member of the invoking class.

Answer (score 1):

Probably some typos an whatnot, but I'd flatten the whole range.

This is based on the idea that the range can be described as

```
x_0 + d_0*(x_1+d_1*(x_2+d_2....)
```

So we can roll our own that way

```
std::vector<int> lower_bound{-4,-5,6};
std::vector<int> upper_bound{6,7,4};

//ranges
std::vector<int> ranges;
for (size_t i = 0; i < lower_bound.size(); i++) {
   ranges.push_back(upper_bound[i]-lower_bound[i]);
}

for (int idx = 0; idx < numel; idx++) {
    //if you don't need the actual indicies, you're done

    //extract indexes
    int idx2 = idx;
    std::vector<int> indexes;
    for (int i = 0; i < ranges.size(); i++) {
      indexes.push_back(idx2%ranges[i]-lower_bound[i]);
      idx2 = idx2/ranges[i];
    }
    //do stuff
    grid[idx] = 2 * indexes[0] + 3 *indexes[1] - 4 * indexes[2];
}
```

Edit: to be more generic:

```
 template <typename D>
 void multi_for(const std::vector<int>& lower_bound, const std::vector<int> upper_bound, D d) {
    std::vector<int> ranges;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < lower_bound.size(); i++) {
       ranges.push_back(upper_bound[i]-lower_bound[i]);
    }
    size_t numel = std::accumulate(ranges.begin(), ranges.end(), std::multiplies<int,int>{});

    for (int idx = 0; idx < numel; idx++) {
        //if you don't need the actual indicies, you're done

        //extract indexes
        int idx2 = idx;
        std::vector<int> indexes;
        for (int i = 0; i < ranges.size(); i++) {
          indexes.push_back(idx2%ranges[i]-lower_bound[i]);
          idx2 = idx2/ranges[i];
        }
        //do stuff
        d(idx,indexes);
     }
 }
 //main
 size_t* grid;//initialize to whateer

std::vector<int> lower_bound{-4,-5,6};
std::vector<int> upper_bound{6,7,4};

 auto do_stuff = [grid](size_t idx, const std::vector<int> indexes) {
    grid[idx] = 2 * indexes[0] + 3 *indexes[1] - 4 * indexes[2];
 };

 multi_for(lower_bound,upper_bound,do_stuff);
```

Comment: Thanks I actually have functions which gives index to coordinates and its reciprocal coordinates to index. But since I need the indices in my do stuff it won't fit for my needs.

Comment: @coincoin I'm confused why this doesn't fit your needs, as it extracts the indexes. I'll add your "do stuff line" to the code.

Comment: I will try your approach I think it might fit indeed.

Answer (score 1):

An iterative approach could look like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
  std::vector<int> lower_bound({-4, -5, -6});
  std::vector<int> upper_bound({ 6,  7,  4});

  auto increase_counters = [&](std::vector<int> &c) {
    for(std::size_t i = 0; i < c.size(); ++i) {
      // This bit could be made to look prettier if the indices are counted the
      // other way around. Not that it really matters.
      int &ctr    = c          .rbegin()[i];
      int  top    = upper_bound.rbegin()[i];
      int  bottom = lower_bound.rbegin()[i];

      // count up the innermost counter
      if(ctr + 1 < top) {
        ++ctr;
        return;
      }

      // if it flows over the upper bound, wrap around and continue with
      // the next.
      ctr = bottom;
    }

    // end condition. If we end up here, loop's over.
    c = upper_bound;
  };

  for(std::vector<int> counters = lower_bound; counters != upper_bound; increase_counters(counters)) {
    for(int i : counters) {
      std::cout << i << ", ";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
  }
}
```

...although whether this or a recursive approach is more elegant rather depends on the use case.

Comment: Thank you again for your help. Your approach looks also nice  !

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <typename Func>
void process(const std::vector<int>& lower, const std::vector<int>& upper, Func f)
{
    std::vector<int> temp;
    process(lower, upper, f, 0, temp);
}

template <typename Func>
void process(const std::vector<int>& lower, const std::vector<int>& upper, Func f,
    int index, std::vector<int>& current)
{
    if (index == lower.size())
    {
        f(current);
        return;
    }

    for (int i = lower[index]; i < upper[index]; ++i)
    {
        current.push_back(i);
        process(lower, upper, f, index + 1, current);
        current.pop_back();
    }
}

int main()
{
    // Dimension here is 3D
    std::vector<int> lower_bound({-4, -5, 6});
    std::vector<int> upper_bound({6, 7, 4});
    // Replace the lambda below with whatever code you want to process
    // the resulting permutations.
    process(lower_bound, upper_bound, [](const std::vector<int>& values)
    {
        for (std::vector<int>::const_iterator it = values.begin(); it != values.end(); ++it)
        {
            std::cout << *it << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    });
}
```