# Initializing An Array of Unknown Dimensionality

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

I was surprised that I couldn't find this question existing.  I've tried to generalize it (with some nice untested code) to something everyone can benefit from.

Suppose I have a multidimensional `Point`:

```
template <int dims> class Point { public: double data[dims]; };
```

Now I create a multidimensional array of them:

```
 template <int dims> void foobar(int count0, ...) {
    //Using variadic function.  Could also use variadic templates in C++ (arguably better)
    int counts[dims], total_count=count0; counts[0]=count0;
    va_list args; va_start(args,count0);
    for (int i=1;i<dims;++i) {
        int count = va_arg(args,int);
        counts[i] = count;
        total_count *= count;
    }
    va_end(args);

    Point<dims>* array = new Point<dims>[total_count];

    //...
}
```

As you can see, `array` is a multidimensional array of unknown dimensionality, represented in a 1D array.

---

**My question: how can I *cleanly* initialize this array to its multidimensional grid points?**

Here's the example behavior I want in 1, 2, and 3 dimensions.  Obviously, I don't want to write this for every possible dimensionality I might want to use!  The goal is to *generalize* this.

```
//Example: dim==1
for (int x=0; x<counts[0]; ++x) {
    Point<1>& point = array[x];
    point.data[0] = (x+0.5) / (double)counts[0];
}

//Example: dim==2
for (int y=0; y<counts[1]; ++y) {
    for (int x=0; x<counts[0]; ++x) {
        Point<2>& point = array[y*counts[0]+x];
        point.data[0] = (x+0.5) / (double)counts[0];
        point.data[1] = (y+0.5) / (double)counts[1];
    }
}

//Example: dim==3
for (int z=0; z<counts[2]; ++z) {
    for (int y=0; y<counts[1]; ++y) {
        for (int x=0; x<counts[0]; ++x) {
            Point<3>& point = array[(z*counts[1]+y)*counts[0]+x];
            point.data[0] = (x+0.5) / (double)counts[0];
            point.data[1] = (y+0.5) / (double)counts[1];
            point.data[2] = (z+0.5) / (double)counts[2];
        }
    }
}
```

Again, my question: generalize the above for any number of nested loops/dimensions in a clean way.

Note: I've come up with a few *nasty* ways, and they're inelegant and slow.  Especially, I want to avoid recursion, if possible, since this will be called on high-dimensional smallish datasets quite frequently.
Note: There are obvious parallels in C, so either C or C++ is fine.  C++11 preferred.

Comment: What is the source of values? i.e. *to what* we are initializing

Comment: @Drop "initialize this array to its multidimensional grid points". Then see the example following that?

Comment: I've got it, but where do you get exact values for your point array? Just from this: `point.data[i] = (v[i]+0.5) / (double)counts[i];`? I think I don't understand what is "its multidimensional grid points".

Comment: @Drop I think I don't understand what you're asking. That example code is _setting_ the values in the array. I'm setting them to the grid indices `x`, `y`, and `z` (normalized to [0,1])--that is, their position within the multidimensional array.

Comment: Recursion still might work, you only recurse at most the amount of dimensions, could you better define "high dimensional"

Comment: It also should be posible to do this by reversing the mapping from N dim to 1 and just looping through the 1D projection, but I'll need to think on that

Answer (score 1):

**Edit in response to comment and updated question**

If you need performance and "elegancy" I would :

- drop your multidimensional array approach and flatten it (i.e. one array dimension). No `new`, no pointer, use a C++ modern approach with `std::vector` or `std::array`.
- provide an abstract container for your multi dim array with convenient methods such as a generic nested loop "generator"
- Replace your variadic arguments with a fixed size array (since you know `dims` at compile time.

So I have found a following solution which is quite coherent with your implementation and needs, and try to remain simple.

I have managed rewriting a little MultiArray class in a "modern C++11 way". I consider here that the `count` dimensions might not be known at compile time hence the use of `std::vector` now. It is of course possible to have a more generic and compile time code with `std::array` see my original answer below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>

template<size_t DIMS>
class MultiArray {
public:
    // Point here is just an array
    using Point = std::array<double,DIMS>;

    // fill data_ with an init array
    // not that count is just a fix sized array here no variadic arguments needed
    MultiArray(const std::array<size_t, DIMS>& count) 
        : data_{init_array(count)} {}

private:   
    // the init functions are used for the constructor
    void init_point(Point& point, const std::array<size_t,DIMS>& coord, const std::array<size_t, DIMS>& count) {
        std::cout << " -> { ";
        for (size_t i = 0; i < DIMS; i ++) {
            point[i] = (coord[i] + 0.5) / count[i];
            std::cout << point[i] << ";";
        }
        std::cout << " }\n";
    }

    std::vector<Point> init_array(const std::array<size_t, DIMS>& count) {
        std::vector<Point> data(std::accumulate(count.begin(), count.end(), 1, std::multiplies<int>())); // accumulate computes the prod of DIMS total_count
        std::array<size_t, DIMS> current{};
        size_t i=0;
        do {
             for (size_t i = 0; i < DIMS; i ++)
                 std::cout << current[i] << ";";
            init_point(data[i++],current,count);
        } while (increment(current, count));
        return data;
    }

    // the following function allows to imitate the nested loop by incrementing multidim coordinates
    bool increment( std::array<size_t, DIMS>& v, const std::array<size_t, DIMS>& upper) {
        for (auto i = v.size(); i-- != 0; ) {
            ++v[i];
            if (v[i] != upper[i]) {
                return true;
            }
            v[i] = 0;
        }
        return false;
    }   
private:
    std::vector<Point> data_; // A flatten multi dim vector of points
};


int main() {
   std::array<size_t, 3> count{{4,5,3}};
   MultiArray<3> test{count};
}
```

**<kbd>[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e33ef1a1f6ac42da)</kbd>**

As you can see in results `data_` can be initialized generically for `N`  dimensions. If you need a higher level abstract class, you can check below my original answer where you can perform some convenient operations (i.e. access to `grid[{i,j,k}]` for filling the values).

**Original answer**

I needed a multi dimensional grid for my needs and happened to ask improvements of my code on [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/97260/generic-multi-dimension-grid-array-class-in-c). Here a working [example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/96cf1e8570143d6f) where of course some features might be unnecessary for you... My implementation relates on template and compile time computations. Note that the dimensions size must be known at compile time.

Briefly, the class would look like this :

```
template<typename T, size_t... DIMS> // variadic template here for the dimensions size
class MultiGrid {
   // Access from regular idx such as grid[64]
   T& operator[] (size_type idx)       { return values_[idx]; };
   // Access from multi dimensional coordinates such as grid[{6,3,4}]
   T& operator[] (const std::array<size_t,sizeof...(DIMS)>& coord)       { // can give code for runtime here };
private:
  std::array<T,sizeof...(DIMS)> data_;
}
```

And then you can construct your multidimensional array and initialize it these ways :

```
MultiGrid<float,DIM1,DIM2,DIM3> data; // 3D
// MultiGrid<float,DIM1,DIM2,DIM3,DIM4> data; // 4D
// etc...

// initialize it like this with nested arrays
for (size_t z=0; z < DIM3; z ++)
  for (size_t y=0; y < DIM2; y ++)
    for (size_t x=0; x < DIM1; x ++)
      data[{x,y,z}] = [...] // whatever

// or like this in C++11/14 way
for (auto &x : data) x = [...] // this is convenient to provide a container like approach since no nested arrays are needed here.
```

In case you need to specify an algorithm for variadic nested loops for filling out the values you can take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27567859/variadic-nested-loops) and do it this way with the first answer :

```
// here lower_bound is 0-filled vector
std::vector<int> current = lower_bound;
do {
   data[current] = [...] // fill in where current is a coordinate
} while (increment(current, lower_bound, upper_bound));
```

If you need something I miss in my implementation feel free to ask. I would also be glad if someone can point out improvements.

Comment: How does this generalize N depth nested loops?

Comment: With variadic template, you can have a N multi dimensional array. e.g. `MultiGrid<float,DIM1,DIM2,DIM3,DIM4,DIM5>`.

Comment: @coincoin Glenn is hinting at the problem here. I can easily make a multidimensional array that looks pretty, but _filling_ it still isn't. The nested arrays example I gave is the _behavior_ I want, not the implementation: I _do not_ want to write nested for loops by hand for every possible dimensionality I might care to use. The difficulty is initializing it to grid points, as I showed in my example.

Comment: What about in my second example where you can fill the array through iterators (single loop) ? I think whether it is possible to do it depend on the way you fill your values can you explain how you want to initialize it in order to see if we can do better ?

Comment: The single loop could work, but only if you can better specify how. The behavior is as in my example above. In pseudocode, for each array element, do `array[a][b][c]...[z] = new Point(a,b,c,...,z);`.

Answer (score 1):

Going from `X,Y,Z` to the flattened array (F) we have the following equation

```
F=(Z*DimY+y)*DimX+X
```

or

```
F=Z*DimY*DimX+Y*DimX+X

X = F % DimX
Y = F % DimX*DimY/DimX
Z = F % DimX*DimY*DimZ/DimX*DimY
```

in a 7 x 3 x 5 array, Z=3, Y=1, X=2 would be at `3`*3*5 + `1`*5 + `2`= 45+5+2=`52`

```
X = `52` % 5 = 2
Y = `52` % (5 * 3) / 5 = 7 / 5 = 1
Z = `52` % (7 * 5 * 3)/15 = 52/15 = 3
```

in a 7 x 3 x 5 array, Z=4, Y=2, X=3 would be at `4`*3*5 + `2`*5 + `3`= 60+10+3=`73`

```
X = `73` % 5 = 3
Y = `73` % (5 * 3) / 5 = 13 / 5 = 2
Z = `73` % (7 * 5 * 3)/15 = 73/15 = 4
```

If we keep the cumulative products in an array, `mult` `{ 1, X, X*Y, X*Y*Z, ...}` and all points in an array, `val`

Points to flat array:

```
F=sum(mult[i]*val[i]);
```

Flat array to points:

```
i[0]=F%mult[1]/mult[0];
i[1]=F%mult[2]/mult[1];
...
```

We can then iterate over F (the flat array) , reverse engineer from the index into the flat array all points: X,Y,... as above and do the initialization you want in a generic loop:

Given `mult` as `mult[0]=1; mult[d+1]=mult[d]*count[d];`

```
for (int i = 0; i < total_count; ++i) {
    for (int d=0; d < dims; ++d) {
      int dim=(i%mult[d+1])/mult[d];
      point.data[d] = (dim+0.5) / (double)counts[d];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution, using C++11 variadic templates and pack expansions.

My "foobar" compiles as a `constexpr` function so I'd say that's pretty efficient :p

As for elegance, you can be the judge, but I think it's pretty good.

Basically the idea is to replace `for` loops with a functional programming way of doing iteration, where we just seek to explicitly build the set we want to iterate over first. That code can then be generalized to arbitrary dimensionality in a more straightforward way.

The code is totally self-contained save for `<array>` header.

It compiles for me at C++11 standard with gcc 4.8.2 and clang 3.6.

Note: If you want to use the same technique for code where the dimensions are a run-time parameter, basically what you would do is reimplement the `Cartesian_Product` metafunction below as a run-time function using something like `std::vector<std::vector<size_t>>`. Then you can build your iteration set by taking `dim` number of cartesian products, and iterate over that using a single for loop to populate the result.

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

/////////////////////////////////////////////
// The point class from problem statement
/////////////////////////////////////////////

template <size_t dims> class Point { public: double data[dims]; };

// Some basic type list and meta function objects to work with

// List of indices
template<size_t... sl>
struct StList {
    static constexpr size_t length = sizeof...(sl);
};

// Metafunction to compute a volume
template <typename T>
struct Compute_Volume;

template<size_t s>
struct Compute_Volume<StList<s>> {
    static constexpr size_t value = s;
};

template <size_t s1, size_t s2, size_t... sl>
struct Compute_Volume<StList<s1, s2, sl...>> {
    static constexpr size_t value = s1 * Compute_Volume<StList<s2, sl...>>::value;
};

// Concatenate
template<typename TL, typename TR>
struct Concat;

template<size_t... SL, size_t... SR>
struct Concat<StList<SL...>, StList<SR...>> {
    typedef StList<SL..., SR...> type;
};

template<typename TL, typename TR>
using Concat_t = typename Concat<TL, TR>::type;

// Meta function to check if a typelist is component-wise less than another typelist
// For testing purposes
template <typename TL, typename TR>
struct all_less_than;

template <size_t l1, size_t... SL, size_t r1, size_t... SR>
struct all_less_than<StList<l1, SL...>, StList<r1, SR...>> {
    static constexpr bool value = (l1 < r1) && all_less_than<StList<SL...>, StList<SR...>>::value;
};

template<>
struct all_less_than<StList<>, StList<>> {
    static constexpr bool value = true;
};

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// constexpr template function for the point initializations you described
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
template <typename index, typename dims>
struct point_maker;

template <size_t... idx, size_t... dim>
struct point_maker<StList<idx...>, StList<dim...>> {
    static_assert(sizeof...(idx) == sizeof...(dim), "misuse of 'point_maker' template, idx and dim must have same number of coordinates");
    static_assert(all_less_than<StList<idx...>, StList<dim...>>::value, "misuse of 'point_maker' template, idx is out of bounds");
    static constexpr Point<sizeof...(idx)> make_point() {
        return {{ ((idx + 0.5) / static_cast<double>(dim))... }};
    }
};

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Now we need to abstract the for loops. We need a little more infrastructure for this.
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// A basic typelist object
template <typename... tl>
struct TypeList {
    static constexpr size_t length = sizeof...(tl);
};

// Specialization for the Concat metafunction
template<typename... TL, typename... TR>
struct Concat<TypeList<TL...>, TypeList<TR...>> {
    typedef TypeList<TL..., TR...> type;
};


// Metafunction to compute the cartesian product of two lists of lists, and evaluate the `Concat` metafunction for each pair.
template <typename S, typename T>
struct Cartesian_Product;

template <typename s1, typename s2, typename... sl, typename T>
struct Cartesian_Product<TypeList<s1, s2, sl...>, T> {
    typedef Concat_t<typename Cartesian_Product<TypeList<s1>, T>::type, typename Cartesian_Product<TypeList<s2, sl...>, T>::type> type;
};

template <typename s, typename t1, typename t2, typename... tl>
struct Cartesian_Product<TypeList<s>, TypeList<t1, t2, tl...>> {
    typedef Concat_t<typename Cartesian_Product<TypeList<s>, TypeList<t1>>::type, typename Cartesian_Product<TypeList<s>, TypeList<t2, tl...>>::type> type;
};

template <typename s, typename t>
struct Cartesian_Product<TypeList<s>, TypeList<t>> {
    typedef TypeList<Concat_t<s, t>> type;
};

template <typename S, typename T>
using Cartesian_Product_t = typename Cartesian_Product<S, T>::type;

// Some unit tests for the above :)

static_assert( std::is_same<Cartesian_Product_t<TypeList<StList<1>, StList<2>>, TypeList<StList<3>, StList<4>>>, TypeList<StList<1,3>, StList<1,4>, StList<2,3>, StList<2,4>>>::value , "cartesian product not working");

static_assert( std::is_same<Cartesian_Product_t<TypeList<StList<1,5>, StList<2>>, TypeList<StList<3>, StList<4>>>, TypeList<StList<1,5,3>, StList<1,5,4>, StList<2,3>, StList<2,4>>>::value , "cartesian product not working");

static_assert( std::is_same<Cartesian_Product_t<TypeList<StList<1,5>, StList<2>>, TypeList<StList<>>>, TypeList<StList<1,5>, StList<2>>>::value , "cartesian product not working");

// Metafunction to count from 0 to n

// Count from zero to n-1, and make a sequence of singleton sets containing the numbers
template<size_t s>
struct Count {
    typedef Concat_t<typename Count<s-1>::type, TypeList<StList<s-1>>> type;
};

template<>
struct Count<0> {
    typedef TypeList<> type;
};

template<size_t s>
using Count_t = typename Count<s>::type;


// Metafunction to abstract a series of for loops, generating the list of all the index tuples the collection of loops would generate

template <typename T>
struct Volume_Maker;

template <>
struct Volume_Maker<StList<>> {
    typedef TypeList<StList<>> type;
};

template <size_t s, size_t... sl>
struct Volume_Maker<StList<s, sl...>> {
    typedef Cartesian_Product_t<Count_t<s>, typename Volume_Maker<StList<sl...>>::type> type;
};

template <typename T>
using Volume_t = typename Volume_Maker<T>::type;

// Some more quick unit tests

template <typename T>
struct Volume_Test {
    static_assert( Volume_t<T>::length == Compute_Volume<T>::value, "volume computation mismatch");
};

Volume_Test<StList<1,2,3>> test1{};
Volume_Test<StList<1,1,1>> test2{};
Volume_Test<StList<1>> test3{};
Volume_Test<StList<7,6,8>> test4{};

/////////////////
// Grand finale
/////////////////

template <typename dim_list, typename idx_list = Volume_t<dim_list>>
struct foobar_helper;

template <size_t... dim, typename... idx>
struct foobar_helper<StList<dim...>, TypeList<idx...>> {
    typedef StList<dim...> dim_list;
    typedef std::array<Point<sizeof...(dim)>, sizeof...(idx)> array_type;

    static constexpr array_type make_array() {
        return {{ point_maker<idx, dim_list>::make_point()... }};
    }
};

template <size_t... dim>
constexpr std::array<Point<sizeof...(dim)>, Compute_Volume<StList<dim...>>::value> foobar() {
    return foobar_helper<StList<dim...>>::make_array();
}

/////////////////
// Example usage
/////////////////

template <size_t ndim>
std::ostream & operator << (std::ostream & s, const Point<ndim> & p) {
    s << "[ ";
    for (size_t i = 0; i < ndim; ++i) {
        if (i) { s << ", "; }
        s << p.data[i];
    }
    s << " ]";
    return s;
}

template<size_t ndim, size_t N>
void print_array(std::ostream & s, const std::array<Point<ndim>, N> & a) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        s << a[i] << std::endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    constexpr auto array1 = foobar<2,2,2>();
    print_array(std::cout, array1);

    constexpr auto array2 = foobar<3,3,3,3>();
    print_array(std::cout, array2);
}
```

Comment: You seem to have fun too :)